# React Native: Chain Async Calls. e.g to AsyncStorage?

Tags: javascript, promise, react-native

I'm trying to chain several calls to AsyncStorage.getItem() but cannot seem to get the calls to trigger in the correct order. I seem to manage to drop out of the loop with the last item completed before earlier items. It appears that React uses a different syntax for promises than how jQuery would work.

In this example I am trying to chain calls to get vars v1, v2, v3. v3 triggers a refresh of the UI for which vars v1 and v2 are required. My code for two chained vars is as follows:

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("v1")
.then(
    (value) => {
        if (value !== null){
            varCollection.v1 =value
        }
    }
)
.then( () => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("v3")
    .then((value) => {
        if (value !== null){
            varCollection.v3 = value;
        }else{
            varCollection.v3 = "default value";
        }
    })
    .done()
})
.done();
```

This appears to work but it may be simply luck that causing it to work as when I add another link to the chain, things go wrong.

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("v1")
.then(
    (value) => {
        if (value !== null){
            varCollection.v1 =value
        }
    }
)
.then( () => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("v2")
    .then((value) => {
        if (value !== null){
            varCollection.v2 = value;
        }
    })
    .done()
})
.then( () => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("v3")
    .then((value) => {
        if (value !== null){
            varCollection.v3 = value;
        }else{
            varCollection.v3 = "default value";
        }
    })
    .done()
})
.done();
```

This results in v3 altering and triggering the state of the app to change even though v2 may not have been assigned yet.

Calling console.log() on each of the vars in props.varCollection from getInitialState() of child elements shows v1 is present but v2 isn't or vice versa. I have also tried nesting my calls to create the chain which I realised gets messy quickly.

*** Update ***
Further to SLacks and Bergi's suggestions I have also tried the following:

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("v1")
.then((value) => {
    if (value !== null){
        v1 = value;
    }
})
.then( () =>{
    return( 
        AsyncStorage.getItem("v2")
        .then((value) => {
            if (value !== null){
                v2 = value;
            }
        })
    )
})
.then( () => {
    return(
        AsyncStorage.getItem("v3")
        .then((value) => {
            if (value !== null){
                v3 = value;
            }
        })
    )
})
.done();
```

and

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("v1")
.then((value) => {
    if (value !== null){
        v1 = value;
    }
})
.then( () =>
    ( 
        AsyncStorage.getItem("v2")
        .then((value) => {
            if (value !== null){
                v2 = value;
            }
        })
    )
)
.then( () => 
    (
        AsyncStorage.getItem("v3")
        .then((value) => {
            if (value !== null){
                v3 = value;
            }
        })
    )
)
.done();
```

but still get stuck at the second call.

*** /Update ***

What is the correct way to chain Async calls in React Native?

Comment: You need to return the promises to the chain.

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure why the suggested syntax from Bergi did not work but I found that separating the call and assignment before and after the then statement allowed strict control of ordering and that the return statement should only return the promise from the last call in each block. This may not be the best way to do it, but it seems to work quite well for sequential synchronous reads.

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("v1")
.then( (value) =>
      {
        this.setState({v1:value})
        return AsyncStorage.getItem("v2")
      }
)
.then( (value) =>
    {
        this.setState({v2: value})
        return AsyncStorage.getItem("v3")
    }
)
.then( (value) =>
    {
        this.setState({v3:value})
        return AsyncStorage.getItem("v4")
    }
)
.then( (value) =>
    {
        return this.setState({v4:value})
    }
).done();
```

You can see it in action at https://rnplay.org/plays/51t0cQ

Answer (score 2):

You need to `return` those promises from the `then` callbacks. Just put a `return` statement in front of each, or omit the block braces of your arrow function.

Then you also will only need one single `.done()` in the end.

Comment: Thanks but I'm having trouble implementing this. I have tried both suggestions but cannot get them to go further than the second item still. I will edit the question to include the variations that I have tried.

Comment: I've now edited the question to include the code as I thought you had suggested. Any ideas?

Comment: Hm, those seem fine. You might want to double-check that they compile to `return` statements in the ES5 code. Other than that, the promise implementation you are using might be bogus, but I can't believe that.

Comment: Ok, I worked it out. Adding the return where you had said, didn't work for me, but adding it before the next queued up call works well and then assigning the value in the next code block instead.. Thank you for you input.

Answer (score 1):

Update: React native supports es7 async await now.
So you can do something like this now,

```
let x = await <Promisified/async functions>
let y = //use x
```

and don't forget to wrap then in try,catch ;)